# Scalatest run code before and after specific test

Tags: scala, scalatest

I want to ask a quick question.

Is there a way to run some code before and after a specific test?

Imagine for a moment that I want some environment-setup code to be executed before and after a specific test, but not in all tests.

I've tried to define a function to do that for me and just call that function ant the beginning and the end of my test. It works fine but if the test fails, the function I call at the end isn't called (since the test failed).

Is there a way to restrict the beforeAndAfter trait to be executed only at specific tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this (or a variation of this):

```
def beforeAfter[T](before: =>Unit, after: =>Unit)(t: =>T) = {
  before
  try t
  finally after
}
```

Then

```
beforeAfter(before = action1, after = action2) {
  test
}
```